# delay_ms() not working in Atmega 16A PU 1703

Tags: microcontroller, led, atmega, atmel

I am using a Atmega 16A PU 1703 to blink a LED. I am using CV AVR IDE to write and  compile code into hex and using progisp to load the hex file onto the microcontroller.

The problem is LED does not blink. It keeps remain glown.

I have set the clock to 8MHz.
 Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/syedsouban/62ae68549d506f767df7d0afe72fe2c2) generated by CV AVR and here is the main logic of the program:

```
while (1)
  {
  // Place your code here   
    PORTA.0=1;  
    delay_ms(1000);
    PORTA.0=0;
    delay_ms(1000);
  }
```

PS: I am a beginner in programming a microcontroller, so guys please be gentle with me.

Is there a problem with fuse bits? I used H and L fuse as D9 and E4 respectively

Comment: Where is F_CPU defined?

Comment: It is not required to define F_CPU when using CV AVR. The clock is set when the project is created

Comment: Have you set up the pin as an  output?

Comment: Yes I made the pin as output

Comment: Are you sure you have the LED on the correct pin? What happens if you comment out the “PORTA.0=1” line? Does the LED remain off?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure. I tried commenting PORTA.0=1 the led didn't glow at all. I think there is a problem with delay or with fuse bits

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask a question, but I'll guess that you wonder why your blinking LED doesn't blink.

You set the port bit high, wait a second, then set it low.  Then the loop repeats, instantly setting the bit high again.

Try adding another delay_ms(1000) after PORTA.0=0 so you'll have a bit of time to see the result of the port bit being LOW.

Comment: Yeah that's what I wanted to ask. I tried adding delay_ms(1000) after PORTA.0=0 but the led is not blinking. It remains glowed all the time

Answer (score 0):

Try using LATA.0 instead of PORTA.0. It might be an issue with read-modify-write.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to hook up a logic analyzer or oscilloscope (whatever you have available) to see if the pin is toggling at all. You can also measure the delay that way.